# How does UTF-16 encoding use surrogate code points?

Tags: unicode, utf-16

According to the [Unicode specification](http://www.unicode.org/versions/Unicode13.0.0/ch03.pdf)

> *D91 UTF-16 encoding form*: The Unicode encoding form that assigns each
> Unicode scalar value in the ranges U+0000..U+D7FF and U+E000..U+FFFF
> to a single unsigned 16-bit code unit with the same numeric value as
> the Unicode scalar value, and that **assigns each Unicode scalar value
> in the range U+10000..U+10FFFF to a surrogate pair**.

The term "scalar value" is referred to unicode code points, that is the range of abstract ideas which must be encoded into specific byte sequence by different encoding forms (UTF-16 and so on). So it seems that this excerpt gist is in view of not all code points can be accommodated into one UTF-16 code unit (two bytes), there are ones which should be encoded into a pair of code units - 4 bytes (it's called "a surrogate pair").

However, the very term "scalar value" is defined as follows:

> *D76 Unicode scalar value:* Any Unicode code point except high-surrogate
> and low-surrogate code points.

Wait... Does the Unicode have surrogate code *points*? What's the reason for it when UTF-16 can use 4 bytes to represent scalar points? Can anyone explain the rationale and how UTF-16 uses this code points?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, Unicode reserves ranges for surrogate code points:

- [High Surrogate Area U+D800 to U+DBFF](https://www.unicode.org/charts/PDF/UD800.pdf)
- [Low Surrogate Area U+DC00 to U+DFFF](https://www.unicode.org/charts/PDF/UDC00.pdf)

Unicode reserves these ranges because these 16-bit values are used in surrogate pairs and no other symbol can be assigned to them.  Surrogate pairs are two 16-bit values that encode code points above U+FFFF that do not fit into a single 16-bit value.

Answer (score 2):

Just for the sake of ultimate clarification.

UTF-16 uses 16-bits (2-bytes) code units. It means this encoding format encodes code points (= abstract ideas should be represented in computer memory in some way), as a rule, into 16 bits (so an interpreter presumably reads data as two bytes at a time).

UTF-16 does its best quite straightforward: the `U+000E` code point would be encoded as `0x000E`, `U+000F` as `0x000F`, and so on.

The issue is that 16 bits are not sufficient to accommodate all unicode code points (the `0x0000` - `0xFFFF` range allows of only 65 536 possible values). We might use two 16-bits words (4 bytes) for the code points beyond these boundaries (actually, my misunderstanding was about why UTF-16 doesn't do so). However, this approach results in a bitter inability to decode some values. For example, if we encode the `U+10000` code point into `0x00010000` how on earth the interpreter should decode such representation: as two different successive code points, `U+0001` and `U+0000`, or as a single one, `U+10000`?

The Unicode specification decided on a better way. If there is a need to encode the `U+10000` - `U+10FFFF` range (there are 1 048 576 code points by the way) then we should, first, set apart 1 024 + 1 024 = 2 048 values from one byte range (the spec chose the `0xD800` - `0xDFFF` ones for these purposes). And when the interpreter encounters a `0xD800` - `0xDBFF` value it knows there is no implied "full-fledged" code point encoded here (no *scalar value* in terms of the spec) and it should then read another 16 bits to get a value from the `0xDC00` - `0xDFFF` range and finally conclude which of the `U+10000` - `U+10FFF` code points was encoded with these 4 bytes. Note this scheme makes possible to encode 1 024 * 1 024 = 1 048 576 code points (and that's the very number we need).

The Unicode spec just includes this integer range in its *Unicode code space*, which is a space of code points from `U+0000` to `0x10FFFF`. Then the `U+D800` - `U+DBFF` subspace is called *High Surrogate Area* and `U+DC00` - `U+DFFF` *Low Surrogate Area* therein. Since the values of these code *points* match those of UTF-16 code *units* (= the specific representations of code points), this inclusion can be viewed as a UTF-16 relic:

> The high-surrogate and low-surrogate code points are designated for
> surrogate code units in the UTF-16 character encoding form. They are
> unassigned to any abstract character. [[spec](https://www.unicode.org/versions/Unicode15.0.0/ch03.pdf)]

Comment: Looks like an important typo in “Then the U+D800 - U+DFFF subspace” in your last paragraph. Should be “U+DBFF” as defined [here](https://www.unicode.org/charts/PDF/UD800.pdf)?

Comment: @triplee, I dont understand the question;  "the how on earth the interpreter should decode such representation..." Is it possible for you to expand on this a little more?

Comment: I'm guessing they are trying to say, "there was no way in a pure 16-bit encoding to express a code point with more than 16 bits, because then you would never be sure whether four bytes represent a single code point or two distinct code points". This is why surrogates had to be invented, as a way to extend the encoding so it is no longer purely a 16-bit encoding, with unambiguous representations of sequences which represent more than 16 bits. (The purely 16-bit encoding still exists, and is called UCS-2. Obviously, it cannot represent code point outside the BMP.)

Comment: @BasilBourque I concur with your analysis, enough that I have now corrected the apparent typo.